# i can not remove a file ,the rm do not work, why?

Tags: xml, encoding, macros, utf-8, terminal

when i ***ls*** my file Color Schemes

```
  ~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Color Schemes » ls     
MidnightBlue.bbcolors
MidnightBlue.bbcolors<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Solarized Dark.bbcolors
Solarized Light.bbcolors
```

there is a `MidnightBlue.bbcolors<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` which i dont want.

But i can't delete it.

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Color Schemes » rm -f MidnightBlue.bbcolors<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

or

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Color Schemes » rm -r MidnightBlue.bbcolors<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

how can i delete it?

thx a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put quotes around your file name, because otherwise the `<` is an input redirection operator.

```
rm -f 'MidnightBlue.bbcolors<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

should do the trick.